# Getting data from xml respose in nifi

Tags: xml, apache-nifi

After strating invokehttp processor i get response data  like that:

```
<Response xmlns="">
<Result>
<ResponseStatus>false</ResponseStatus>
<Error>
<ErrorCode>-7</ErrorCode>
<ErrorDescription>not foudn</ErrorDescription>
</Error>
</Result>
</Response>
```

i needed  the  value  of ErrorCode (-7) so i have added EvaluateXpath processor  with attribute ErrorCode i used command `//Error/ErrorCode/text()` but it can't reitreive data of errorcode in  attribute ErrorCode( in  flowfile after processing EvaluateXpath ErrorCode attribute doesn't have  value ,is empty string) how can i get  the  value  of ErrrorCode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract the desired value, use the XPath expression `//ErrorCode`. This will return a `String` value **-7**. By selecting `Destination` **flowfile-attribute**, you can keep the flowfile content constant and put this new value in a flowfile attribute (i.e. named `attribute`).

[image: Configuration of EvaluateXPath]

You can chain the `matched` relationship to an `UpdateAttribute` processor which has the expression `${attribute:toNumber()}` to convert it to a numerical representation, i.e. `${attribute:toNumber():plus(10)}` would return **3**.

[image: Output of LogAttribute]